# C#: adding a new row to datagrid with values from textboxes using bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview and textboxes all bound to a bindingsource. I also have buttons for actions Create and Update. The latter works as intended: the item in the selected row updates with values from the textboxes. Here's the whole code behind the Update button:

```
myBindingSource.EndEdit();
myTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.myTable);
```

The Create button in current implementation adds an empty row and clears all the textboxes, so the only way to add actual values is using the Update button afterwards. Here's the whole code behind the Create button:

```
myBindingSource.CancelEdit();
myBindingSource.AddNew();
```

But I want the Create button to add a row with values already entered into the textboxes, and then clear them. I tried to only use this line:

```
myBindingSource.AddNew();
```

But if I don't cancel pending changes, 1) they'll be applied to the item currently selected in datagridview, 2) an empty row will be added to datagridview.

How can I change the Create button's behavior, so that it added rows with values from the textboxes without affecting currently selected row?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the content of the TextBoxes, which show the content of the `Current` object, to generate a sort of clone of this object and create a new row with its data? If not, is then the User meant to enter new data before a new row has been actually added to the data source (and set a `Current`)?

Comment: @Jimi hello! I meant the latter.

Comment: So, why don't you add a new Row beforehand and set it as the `Current` object, so all bound Controls point to this empty new Row?

Comment: @Jimi, I try to add a new row with myBindingSource.AddNew() but MSDN says that when using AddNew() the EndEdit method is automatically called to commit any pending edit operations. So when I click "Create" the AddNew() method applies changes in textboxes on CURRENT object, then creates a new object.

Comment: Isn't that what is supposed to happen? -> You're currently showing *existing* data in your TextBoxes. Then the User pressed the *New* Button, you add a new Row, move to this new Row, the TextBoxes are now empty, the User enters new data

Comment: @Jimi, as a user you'd probably expect that when you edit textboxes and click "Create" a new row would be added with entered values, otherwise if you click "Update" current row would be edited. And that logic seems impossible to implement with bindingsource :(

Comment: In all input interfaces that I know of, when you ask to *create a new entry*, you're presented with blank input boxes that you have to fill in (except, probably, when some default values are pre-entered in some contexts; something you can do in code, if necessary, **after** you have created a new entry)